# Comparing Two cars using multiple classes

Tags: java, comparison

Hi I have One question that I need help with! My question is that how can I use the "compare" case for two cars that uses multiple classes (Example, UserInput: Compare 1 2 --> Dealership.Class --> Car.class --> Engine.class-->Return with results) and have it return me the difference of both cars, such as MPG, HorsePower, fuelType, and so on! Any explanations would be great as I've tried and failed to do this many times before deciding to get some help. Thank you in advance, and sorry if the code is long! 
Edit: I want my results to be something like, "Car 1 has more Mileage than Car 2, Car 2 is more newer than car 1, and Car 1 and Car 2 both use gas."

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Dealership dealership = new Dealership();
System.out.println("To view a list of commands, enter Commands");

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String[] parts = input.split(" ");
        switch(parts[0])
        {
            case "Commands":
            System.out.println("Compare [n1] [n2]: Compares two cars");
            break;

            case "Compare":
            int index1, index2;
            index1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            index2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            System.out.println("Comparing " + index1 + " & " + index2);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class Dealership 
{
private Car[] cars;
private Car selectedCar;

    public Dealership()
    { 
        cars = new Car[3];

        Engine engine = new Engine(FuelType.Gas, 4, 67001, 162, 24);
        Interior interior = new Interior("Brown", "Maroon", false, false); 
        Trunk trunk = new Trunk(true, false, true, true, "White");
        Car car = new Car("Hyundai", 2006, "Sonata", 2500, "White", CarType.Sedan, engine, interior, trunk);

        cars[0] = car;

        engine = new Engine(FuelType.Gas, 4, 75708, 325, 17);
        interior = new Interior("Black", "Blue", true, false);
        trunk = new Trunk(true, false, true, false, "Black");
        car = new Car("Infiniti", 2016, "QX50", 38000, "Black", CarType.Sedan, engine, interior, trunk);

        cars[1] = car; 

        engine = new Engine(FuelType.Gas, 4, 49967, 132, 26);
        interior = new Interior("White", "Beige", true, true);
        trunk = new Trunk(true, false, true, true, "Brown");
        car = new Car("Toyota", 2010, "Corolla", 7845, "Red", CarType.Sedan, engine, interior, trunk);

        cars[2] = car; 

    }
public String Compare(int index1, int index2) // Left this blank because I just realized I did something wrong here.
    {  
    }
}

public class Car 
{
    private String make;
    private int year;
    private String model;
    private int price;
    private String color;
    private CarType type; 
    private Engine engine;
    private Interior interior;
    private Trunk trunk;
    private Option[] options;
        public Car (String make, int year, String model, int price, String color, CarType type)
        {
            this.make = make;                                           
            this.year = year;  
            this.model = model;
            this.price = price;
            this.color = color;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public Car (String make, int year, String model, int price, String color, CarType type, 
            Engine engine, Interior interior, Trunk trunk)
        {
            this(make, year, model, price, color, type);
            this.engine = engine;
            this.interior = interior;
            this.trunk = trunk;
        }
        String CompareTo (Car otherCar) //Possibly wrong
        {
            if (this.year > otherCar.year) return "Newer";
            if (this.year < otherCar.year) return "Older";
            if (this.price > otherCar.price) return "More expensive";
            if (this.price < otherCar.price) return "Is cheaper"; 
        }
}
enum CarType {Sedan, SUV, CrossOver, Truck}; 

public class Engine
{
    private FuelType fuelType;
    private int noOfCylinders;
    private int capacity; // Gas Tank
    private int horsePower;
    private float mpg;
        public Engine (FuelType fuelType, int noOfCylinders, int capacity, int horsePower, float mpg)
        {
            this.fuelType = fuelType;
            this.noOfCylinders = noOfCylinders;
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.horsePower = horsePower;
            this.mpg = mpg;
        }
//List of Methods Int/Float that I need to add to help me with comparison
        public int getHorsePower()
        {
            if (this.horsePower > anotherCar.horsePower) //Does not work, No Symbol for anotherCar
            return "Has more horsepower"; // Where I'm currently stuck on
        }
        public float getMpg()
        {
            return;
        }
        public FuelType getFuelType()
        {
            return;
        }
        public int getCapacity()
        {
            return;
        }
        public int getNoOfCylinders()
        {
            return;
        }
}
enum FuelType {Gas, Electric, Hybrid, Diesel}
```

Also, I did not add the other 2 classes like Trunk,Interior as it didnt seem necessary.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your compareTo method (though you need a getter for the private fields). Your question might be a little unclear. If you want difference, maybe you want to pass in a string as an argument (e.g: "mpg, horsepower, etc.") and then have a case statement of what you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the best answer but it's just a suggestion that I referred to in the comment I posted for your question.

```
String compareTo (Car otherCar, String property) //Possibly wrong
{
    String message;
    if(property == "MPG") {
      if(this.mpg > otherCar.mpg) return "some message";
      if(this.mpg < otherCar.mpg) return "some message";
    else if(property == "year") {
      if (this.year > otherCar.year) return "Newer";
      if (this.year < otherCar.year) return "Older";
    }
    else if(property == "price") {
      if (this.price > otherCar.price) return "More expensive";
      if (this.price < otherCar.price) return "Is cheaper"; 
    }
  }

}
```

On the other hand, you could do this.

```
String compareByPrice(Car otherCar) {

}

String compareByYear(Car otherCar) {

}

// ... and so forth
```

But the question here would be "do you really need the full car object in the method"? No, you probably only need the field from the car itself.

Comment: I get what you did by doing an if statement, I was hesitating to do that but it looks like its a better choice. Also, for the   If(Property == "MPG") line, MPG is not defined in the Car.Class, but it is defined in the engine class. How would I link those two together? Also thank you so much, this is really helping me:].

Comment: Glad to hear it's helping in some way. For the engine, you already have it linked because your car has the engine object so you can just use "this.engine" or you can make compareTo for the engine as well and make it clear that engine should be responsible for it's own objects, not the car. 

There's also the idea that you can create a Compare class if those comparisons start getting more complex and large but I think that's enough for you to think about for now :).